# Run windows CMD from Android over USB

Tags: android, windows, cmd, usb

I was wondering if it is possible to run a windows cmd.exe command from an android phone which is connected to the target PC via USB. Taking the same effect as `Runtime.getRuntime.exec("explorer.exe");` in java on a windows PC. Is it even possible to do? And is it possible to do this on USB connection?

Answer (score 0):

Telnet is the traditional way. CMD is also the telnet shell in Windows. You have to turn the telnet server on in Windows. Windows, as configured out of the box, requires accounts to have a password for remote access.

Note Telnet is no longer suitable over a network (as it's plain text), but you are just local. Program's like Remote Desktop and PuTTY have replaced Telnet.

PS. Telnet is not installed as standard. You have to choose to install it in Programs and Features.

Comment: That's an option (something fixed function would be safer), but it won't work without doing something like enabling USB tethering, setting up an SSH tunnel through an ADB port forward, or putting both the phone and computer on the same wifi network.